# gem module method cant be included to ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, rubygems

I have a module in my gem

```
module joinSelect
  def self.with
    puts 'with called'
  end
  ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, self
end
```

but I am unable to access method with in any of model classes

```
irb(main):015:0> User.with
NoMethodError: undefined method `with' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

I have tried putting

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  include JoinSelect
#or
  extend JoinSelect

end
``
doesen't work. How can I get "with" accessible on ApplicationRecord ?
Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend to include the module with your code only in the classes that will need that functionality. Including your code in `ActiveRecord::Base` is really not recommended, other gems you may use may conflict with it.

If you need your code to be available on all your ActiveRecord models, then define it in your `ApplicationRecord`. Since all your models will inherit from it, all will gain the functionality.

If you want to add a class method in your AR class, create a module with the function and `extend` it from your class:

```rb
module A
  def foo
    "Hi"
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  extend A
end

User.foo # => "Hi"
```

If you need to do more things, like declaring scopes, using ActiveRecord hooks, etc. then you'll need to use concerns, [see here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

Answer (score 0):

define it without `self` in module

```
module JoinSelect
  def with
    puts 'with called'
  end
end
```

and in ApplicationRecord use extend to include it as a class method

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  extend JoinSelect
end
```